# How does pair and vector work in Graph implementation?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I can't seem to understand how this code is using *adj[i].push_back* format to push elements as I created a 1D vector so pushing into an element should not work (problem-1).
And also on (problem-2) this code is using vector like an 2D vector and outputting through it.
This is a working code. I was struggling to solve a problem on hacker earth. And found this as best submitted.

I have analyzed all the functions of vector STL. Still couldn't find an answer. Checked if I can create 2D vector after declaring 1D vector by using v[i].push_back, It was giving me an error. Checked various tutorials on graph implementation how ever none seem to address how this actually works...

```
vector<pair<int,int>>adj[1001];
int values[100001];
int n,m,k,x,y;
cin>>n>>m>>k;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>values[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    cin>>x>>y;
    adj[x-1].push_back({values[y-1],y-1}); //problem-1
    adj[y-1].push_back({values[x-1],x-1});
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    sort(adj[i].begin(),adj[i].end());
}
int adj_size=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    adj_size=adj[i].size();
    if(k>adj_size)
        cout<<-1<<"\n";
    else
        cout<<(adj[i][adj_size-k].second)+1<<"\n"; //problem-2
}
```

I just need to know how this data is actually stored in the vector.

Comment: I didn't get this: `Checked if I can create 2D vector after declaring 1D vector`. I can't see any 2D vector here.

Comment: `using v[i].push_back, It was giving me an error.`. What error are you getting?

Comment: `T name[K];` declares an array of `T`s with `K` elements. There are 1001 vectors in `adj`.

Comment: On the problem-2 line the format is adj[i] [j] .

Comment: @ShahnewazSiam `adj` is an array of vectors of pairs; `adj[i]` is a vector of pairs; `adj[i][j]` is a pair.

Comment: @KunalPuri  **error: request for member 'push_back' in 'v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(((std::vector<int>::size_type)(b - 1)))', which is of non-class type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}'|**

Comment: @ShahnewazSiam Please share the code that **you** are trying. I don't think the above code is required that much.

Comment: @ShahnewazSiam You can't get that error if the code is working. If you remove the `[1001]` so you only have one vector, you can.

Comment: @KunalPuri I am just trying to understand this code. How ever the link to the problem is : [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/graph-representation/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-learning-graph-3/)
I am trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo This is making more sense now... And yes.. I removed '[1001]' part, and that was causing problem.... Now its becoming clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see it step by step:

```
vector<pair<int,int>>adj[1001];
```

Creating an array of size 1001 of vector. This is equivalent to having `list of edges` for each vertex, the base concept of adjacency list.

Pair is used here because adjacency list is to be sorted on the basis of value and if value is same, then index has to be considered.

```
int values[100001];
int n,m,k,x,y;
cin>>n>>m>>k;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>values[i];
}
```

The above code gets the values from stdin.

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    cin>>x>>y;
    adj[x-1].push_back({values[y-1],y-1}); //problem-1
    adj[y-1].push_back({values[x-1],x-1});
}
```

Here, you are making a undirected graph with x having an edge to y and vice versa.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    sort(adj[i].begin(),adj[i].end());
}
```

Sort each adjacency list in ASCENDING order of values. If value is same, compare index

```
int adj_size=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    adj_size=adj[i].size();
    if(k>adj_size)
        cout<<-1<<"\n";
    else
        cout<<(adj[i][adj_size-k].second)+1<<"\n"; //problem-2
}
```

Return kth element from the end of adjacency list, if it exists. Otherwise, return -1.

**Observation:**

I think this code might fail in case the values are same.

Instead, you should define a custom comparator in `sort`.

Like this:

```
sort(adj[i].begin(),adj[i].end(), [](const pair<int, int> &p1, const pair<int, int> &p2) {
    if (p1.first != p2.first) {
        return p1.first > p2.first;
    }

    return p1.second < p2.second;
});
```

And return kth element from the beginning.

**Suggestion:**

Instead of using this approach, I think you should go for Maxheap.

Comment: Thanks... This explanation actually cleared my doubt. I will try to use Maxheap as you suggested and as for the sorting part.. i didn't realize this issue. Thanks for the suggestion.